# How do I add a property to each object in a call to the dbcontext?

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a Post entity:

```
public class Post
{
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    [NotMapped]
    public bool IsEditable { get; set; }
}
```

If the current logged in User's Id (which is retrieved from a cookie and transformed into an int) is the same as the UserId property, I want to set IsEditable to true (otherwise it is false).

When I retrieve the data I can easily get a list of Posts with the Content and UserId properties by calling:

```
List<Post> posts = await _context.Posts.ToListAsync();
```

However, I want to do something like:

```
_context.Posts.#If CurrentUserId == UserId then Post.IsEditable = true#.ToListAsync();
```

Inside the #'s are where my pseudocode is. Apologies if this is in an incorrect format.

So my ideal result is that it should retrieve the Posts as normal but the only additional thing it does is set that extra IsEditable field.

Comment: An entity class itself shouldn't know anything about editing. Authorization is a cross-cutting concern that should reside in a separate, specialized application layer, which is beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it with [`.ForEach()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.foreach?view=net-7.0) to perform the data mapping/customization on the memory side.

```cs
List<Post> posts = await _context.Posts.ToListAsync();

posts.ForEach(x => 
{
    x.IsEditable = x.UserId == CurrentUserId;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however I am getting some errors. On the first line: For the  A lambda expression with a statement body cannot be converted to an expression tree.

And 

An expression tree may not contain an assignment operator in the first line in the enclosed curly braces.

Comment: Done update the answer. Use `.ForEach()`.